# What is wrong with my print function?

Tags: python, printing, anaconda

I am in an introduction to Anaconda class and I need to write a program to determine how many times a dice roll(s) land on a certain amount of faces. However, I cannot get it to print my answer correctly.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: You may wish to edit this to include the script and error.

Comment: There we go, thanks!

Comment: You really should include the script and error message as text in your question, so we can copy-and-paste into our own Python editors. Just copy-and-paste from your editor or terminal into your question, highlight it, and click the key that looks like `{}` or press Ctrl-K in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your print statement. You try to print a string then something called `end` then another string, and so forth. I think you want that `end` to be an end-of-line character.

Instead of printing something like

```
print("a string" end "another string" end "a third string")
```

use

```
print("a string\n" "another string\n" "a third string")
```

Note that `"\n"` is the end-of-line character in Python. My code also uses a feature of Python where you can combine *string literals* by placing them next to each other. Let lets you see the individual lines more clearly. Your code failed because you tried to do this with a *string variable*, namely `end`, and you did not even define that variable.

Answer (score 1):

From Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

> `print(*objects, sep=’ ‘, end=’\n’, file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

As you can see, the `end` is one of the parameters for the `print()` function, and by default, `end=’\n’`. So to use it correctly, you just have to change the `end` variable (which may not be directly applicable to your code)

Here are some examples:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
    print(i, end =' ')


0 1 2 
>>> for i in range(3):
    print(i, end ='')


012
>>> for i in range(3):
    print(i) # by default end=\n


0
1
2
>>>
```

And also, if I am understanding your logic correctly, the same code can be re-written as such.

```
import random

RollDice = int(input("Number of Rolls:"))
numbers = [0 for _ in range(6)] # array of 6 spaces with int 0

for i in range(RollDice):
    Roll = random.randint(1,6)
    numbers[Roll-1] += 1 # the array index starts from 0 hence you need Roll-1

plusMinus = "+-----"*6 + "+\n" # since you are repeating this you might want to assign it to a variable
print(plusMinus + "| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |\n" + "| " + " | ".join(map(str,numbers)) + " |\n" + plusMinus)
```

P.S. Rather than attaching an image, please copy and paste your code next time, so that we can copy n paste to test.